# git-svn: reset tracking for master

Tags: svn, git, merge, git-svn

I'm using `git-svn` to work with an SVN repository. My working copies have been created using `git svn clone -s http://foo.bar/myproject` so that my working copy follows the default directory scheme for SVN (trunk, tags, branches).

Recently I've been working on a branch which was created using `git-svn branch myremotebranch` and checked-out using `git checkout --track -b mybranch myremotebranch`. I needed to work from multiple locations, so from the branch I `git-svn dcommit`-ed  files to the SVN repository quite regularly.

After finishing my changes, I switched back to the master and executed a merge, committed the merge, and tried to dcommit the successful merge to the remote trunk.

It seems as though after the merge the remote tracking for the master has switched to the branch I was working on:

```
# git checkout master
# git merge mybranch
... (successful)
# git add .
# git commit -m '...'
# git svn dcommit
Committing to http://foo.bar/myproject/branches/myremotebranch ...
#
```

**Is there a way I can update the master so that it's following `remotes/trunk` as before the merge?**

I'm using git 1.7.0.5, if that's any help.

It would be useful if you could also explain *why* this happened, so I can avoid the problem happening again. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here is my current `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    autocrlf = false
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://foo.bar/myproject
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = .
    merge = refs/remotes/myremotebranch
```

So it seems that the trunk is pointing to the correct place. However, switching to the branch then back to the master doesn't help; `git svn dcommit` in the master still tries to push to `myremotebranch`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When there are no changes on trunk, git does a fast-forward merge and simply sets the local "master" branch to the commit on your branch. Git-svn doesn't know how to commit fast-forward merges back to trunk, in fact it thinks "master" now is pointing to the svn branch.

To work around this, use `git merge --no-ff` when merging. This will force git to create a merge commit, which can then be dcommitted to svn.

Comment: To clarify, if I understand, git uses the commit that "master" pointer is on to decide which SVN branch to commit to. That is why the SVN dcommit step fails, since after you completed the merge, and 'mybranch' and 'master' are on the same commit. That commit was originally created from the 'myremotebranch' SVN branch.

Comment: I don't think creating a new merge commit is going to help clarify matters, since the merge info will be lost when it is propagated to the svn repository anyway.

Comment: @Walter: Yes the merge info will not be committed (you keep it in your git repo, though). But without the new merge commit, there's nothing that can be committed to SVN - dcommit would end up doing nothing (which was the problem of the OP).

Answer (score 13):

If you `git svn rebase` after switching back to master and use --squash you can avoid this.

```
# git checkout master
# git svn rebase   //(<--the missing step)
# git merge --squash mybranch // (<-- doesn't commit, more like an svn merge would do)
... (successful)
# git add . 
# git commit -m '...' 
# git svn dcommit
Committing to http://foo.bar/myproject/trunk...
#
```

To solve the current state (i.e. your master is pointing to an SVN branch)

You can 'switch' to another branch, delete master, 'switch' back to it and then merge again:

```
# git checkout mybranch
# git branch -D master
# git checkout -b master trunk
... continue with merge...
# git merge --squash mybranch
```

... you now have mybranch merged into master and ready to `commit` and then  `dcommit` to `trunk`

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation, including the 'to solve the current state' bit. I was in the same pickle, and this worked very neatly to resolve it.

Comment: I don't think `git checkout -b master trunk` is correct. It should be `git checkout -b master remotes/git-svn`

Comment: That would be true if you wanted to work on (i.e. merge to) an SVN branch named "git-svn", but if you are trying to merge to trunk and your SVN repro is "standard" (e.g. has /branches /tags /trunk in the same dir) then `git checkout -b master trunk` is definitely correct

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't made any commit on master, that means the `git merge mybranch` was a fast-forward one: `master HEAD` simply move to `mybranch HEAD`.

That could explain why the `git svn dcommit` pushed your changes to the `SVN mybranch`.
It would:

- first update the corresponding SVN branch with the last Git `mybranch` commits not yet dcommitted,
- record the merge to trunk on the SVN side
- and then it would rebase master on the Git side (nothing to do, already there).

I don't think master hasn't change its reference, but if you have a doubt (and your working directory is clean), you could (if master is currently checked out):

```
git reset --hard remotes/trunk
```

Comment: It seems as though resetting, changing something on the master, `dcommit`ing, then re-merging so there is a conflict, fixing that conflict, then `dcommit`ing fixes the issue. Its not pleasant though.

Comment: @digitala: you mean the reset alone is not enough? The first dcommit after the reset doesn't occur on the SVN trunk?

Answer (score 4):

In general, you should not use `git merge` with `git svn`, because svn, even with branches, doesn't support the kind of merge tracking that git does.  When you need to merge a branch, I've had the most success (at least with recent svn) doing a plain svn checkout/merge process and then using `git svn rebase` to update my git-svn repositories.  This preserves svn's native merge tracking metadata, which (AFAIK) `git-svn` is completely ignorant of.

I'm not totally sure what state your svn repository is in -- I would check to make sure the merge dcommit did what you wanted it to on the trunk.  Even if it did, 
I bet if you look at the contents of the `refs/heads/master` and `refs/remotes/trunk` files in your repo, you'll see that they're different at the moment.  If that's the case, I would (with no local changes present) do a `git-svn fetch` followed by a `git branch -f master remotes/trunk; git reset --hard master` to resync the git branch with the git-svn tracking branch.  If you have local changes, you'll have to commit and do something like `git rebase master^4 --onto remotes/trunk`, where 4 is the number of commits you need to preserve.  Alternatively, if they're all uncommitted, stash them with `git stash` first.

Failing that, you can always get everything into svn and just wipe the repo and get a fresh checkout.

Comment: I agree with that analysis. +1

Answer (score 3):

We have successfully used `git merge --squash` in git-svn feature branch development. The problem with git-svn is that while your local git-svn clone can store the merge information, once you dcommit to the svn repository, it is lost.

So for other (git-)svn users the merge commits look just like plain commits. The squash is good for the same thing as `git merge --no-ff` (eg. producing a merge commit on master), but it also includes a list of the actual commits made in the branch being merged, which would otherwise be lost when dcommitting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I merged remotes/trunk back into master after which git svn info pointed back to trunk

I didn't have the time to actuall dcommit as I was leaving the project and my git-svn repo died with my worstation. I did trythe dcommit --dry-run and it said it would commit back to trunk.

I'll reproduce the setup and test when I get the time

cheers