# Getting git svn to dcommit master to trunk again

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git-svn: reset tracking for master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835791/git-svn-reset-tracking-for-master)

I have a git clone of a Subversion repository that has the standard trunk/branches/tags layout. I cloned the repository using the `--stdlayout` option. I created a branch using

```
git svn branch -m "Creating new branch." mybranch
```

And then checked it out using

```
git checkout --track -b mybranch remotes/mybranch
```

I made a few commits and merged in changes from `master` (equal to `remotes/trunk`). I did `svn dcommit` and it properly committed to the SVN branch `branches/mybranch`.

I switched back to master using

```
git checkout master
```

I merged in the work from `mybranch` using

```
git merge mybranch
```

I then tried to push the merge into trunk using `svn dcommit`, however, git is stuck attempting to push only to `branches/mybranch` instead of `trunk`, even though `master` should be pushing to `trunk`.

I tried making a small change to `master`, committing it locally, and then trying `svn dcommit` again, but it *still* wants to push to `branches/mybranch` instead of `trunk`.

I don't understand what has happened, because `master` used to be following and would push to `trunk`, but no longer does after merging in `mybranch`. How can I get `master` to once again synchronize with `trunk` in the SVN repository, and what can I do in the future to avoid `master` un-following the SVN `trunk`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835791/git-svn-reset-tracking-for-master

Comment: @VonC Thank you! This question is a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: Never use git merge when you are working with git-svn. there are several good blog entries describing how to work with branches when using git-svn.

Comment: @reto If you post links to these blog posts as an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835791/git-svn-reset-tracking-for-master I will gladly up-vote your answer.